# How can we scan a qr code in Blackberry having OS 6 and above

Tags: blackberry, qr-code, blackberry-os6

I need to know whether there is an api or code available to scan a QR code in blackberry having OS6.0 and above . i am new to QR coding section so please guide me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with BlackBerry OS 6 the xzing bar code scanning library is included in the API. RIM has provided a Developers' guide available [here](http://docs.blackberry.com/de-de/developers/deliverables/29251/Barcode_1583481_11.jsp). I suggest you start there, and follow up with other reading. Zxing is a Google library with lots of on-line documentation available.